# Installing gitlab packages

Tags: r, remotes

I have 2 R packages on gitlab, and 2nd package has 1st as dependency. This is making my script which installs all required packages to fail:

```
remotes::install_gitlab(
  "username/package1",
  host = "gitlab.com",
  auth_token = gitlab_token
)

remotes::install_gitlab(
  "username/package2",
  host = "gitlab.com",
  auth_token = gitlab_token,
)
```

Solution which works is to install all other dependency packages for 2nd package before installing it and put `dependencies=FALSE`:

```
remotes::install_gitlab(
  "username/package1",
  host = "gitlab.com",
  auth_token = gitlab_token
)

install.packages(all dependencies for 2nd package except 1st package)

remotes::install_gitlab(
  "username/package2",
  host = "gitlab.com",
  auth_token = gitlab_token,
  dependencies = FALSE
)
```

Is there any other way without 'manually' installing all other required pacakges before installing 2nd package like:

```
 remotes::install_gitlab(
    c("username/package1", "username/package2"),
    host = "gitlab.com",
    auth_token = gitlab_token
 )
```

Comment: The solution may be a little more complicated. You have to look for a sub package in `username/package2` which is needed before. After that `dependencies = TRUE` with all, will work:    : 1) `username/package1` , 2)`mysterious/package` , 3) `username/package2`.

Comment: The `mysterious/package` could be an external low level package like `httpuv`,`Rcpp`,`rlang` etc...

Comment: Isn't this handled by `Remotes` section in `DESCRIPTION` files - https://devtools.r-lib.org/articles/dependencies.html ? For gitlab token, storing it in `GITLAB_PAT` environment variable should work.

Comment: @margusl I've added `Remotes: gitlab::https//gitlab.com/username/package1` in `DESCRIPTION` of package2 but I still get error: `Unknown remote type: gitlab Invalid git repo specification` when using `remotes::install_gitlab`.

Comment: I don't think you write it well, you should try like this `Remotes: gitlab::username/package1` and be sure to have a version of remotes packages higher or equal to 2.3

Comment: At the end this worked for me: `Remotes: gitlab@gitlab.com::username/package1` to the `DESCRIPTION` of `package2`